# Specifying multiple input files in radare2

Tags: radare2

If I want to pass several inputs, I know that I can write this with rarun2:

```
#!/usr/bin/rarun2
stdin="first\nsecond\n"
```

But what if I want to pass the input from a file `file1` at the first time the program is waiting for an input, then from a file `file2`? Is there a way to do this?